# Fixed position horizontal navigation bar getting cut off

Tags: html, user-interface, navigation, uinavigationbar, absolute

My navigation bar keeps getting cut off when the browser window gets too small. I have it as `position: fixed` so that the navigation bar stays in the screen even when the page is scroll down. Doing this though makes it cut off. I also don't want to change the UI to 100%. Because this makes my links go to the next line on the page, but they have borders and it doesn't look professional. I set up a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RvjuP/1/). I think ultimately what I want is it to be fixed vertically, but when people scroll side to side it becomes absolute. I feel that this could be done with javascript, but I have little experience on it. I've seen a few topics on the same subject, but i haven't seen it fixed.

Comment: I am looking for it to be kinda like Facebooks. Shrink the page as small as you can and it allows you to scroll horizontally. Mine for some reason just gets cut off and won't allow you to scroll from side to side.

Comment: taking the width away does the same thing as making the width 100%. It needs to stay stationary and be able for people to scroll side to side and still view the entire bar. I tried making a wrap around the entire page and making it the same width as the bar,but it still cuts it off as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adopt responsive menu then. A demo is [here](http://responsivemobilemenu.com/demo/). Resize your browser to see how the menu adopts itself based on the available width.

Comment: That is the perfect fix. This also solves my mobile device problems, somewhat. I need to remove my social and slideshow parts for that, but this will be useful for that. Thanks! I was actually looking for this type of solution.